# Exception handling requirements

Tags: java, exception

When using specific classes in java, why am I seemingly forced to supply exception handling for certain classes in java api?

such as :

```
private DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
private DocumentBuilder db;

    try {
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch(Exception e) {}
```

Will compile, but :

```
private DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
private DocumentBuilder db;


        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
```

Will not. Why? Could some one please clarify this for me? Can I not just let the possible exception affect my program at runtime without handling it?

Answer (score 2):

Because Java has checked exceptions.  Which means the compiler is going to require you to either *catch* the exception or advertise that your method can potentially *throw* the exception that an invoked method can throw.

[This particular method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newDocumentBuilder()) can throw a `ParserConfigurationException`.

You don't *have* to catch it, but if you don't then you *do* have to advertise this fact on your method.  For example:

```
private void myMethod() throws ParserConfigurationException
```

This tells consuming code that it needs to be prepared to potentially catch and handle the exception.

It's another argument entirely whether or not checked exceptions is a good thing.  The internet has no shortage of debate on the subject.  But that's not something the compiler is going to care about :)

Also note that, while this *compiles*:

```
try {
    db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
} catch(Exception e) {}
```

an empty `catch` block is a *famously* bad idea.  It means you're *catching* the exception, but you're not meaningfully *handling* it.  [The two are *very* different things](http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2012/03/catch-handle.html).

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle website answers my question at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html